# Qt widget destructor indirectly calls widget method via connected signal, and crashes

Tags: c++, qt

I made a widget (QDataflowCanvas) based on `QGraphicsView`, where I connect the signal `QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged()` to the slot `MainWindow::onSelectionChanged` of my main window:

```
void MainWindow::onSelectionChanged()
{
    // canvas is ptr to QDataflowCanvas, subclass of QGraphicsView
    auto selNodes = canvas->selectedNodes();
    auto selConns = canvas->selectedConnections();
    ...
}
```

The problem happens when I close my `MainWindow` and there is some item selected in the `QGraphicsView`.

I don't think I need to provide the complete code (although it can be found [here](https://github.com/fferri/QDataflowCanvas/blob/master/qdataflowcanvas.cpp)), as I already isolated the cause of the crash.

This is what will happen (in order of causality):

- destructor of MainWindow is called
- destructor of QDataflowCanvas is called
- destructor of QGraphicsView is called
- destructor of QGraphicsScene is called, which triggers the removal of all items (with `clear()`)
- destructor of a QGraphicsItem is called
- that will trigger a selectionChange event
- the MainWindow::onSelectionChanged slot is called
- method QDataflowCanvas::selectedNodes() is called, but the object is destroyed
- crash!

which can be seen more in detail from the stack trace of the crash:

[image: stack trace from Qt Creator]

I found this workaround: if I disconnect the signal in `MainWindow::~MainWindow`, it will of course not crash:

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    QObject::disconnect(canvas->scene(), &QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged, this, &MainWindow::onSelectionChanged);
}
```

But this seems a rather atypical practice: I never found myself having to manually severe signal-slot connections because the program would otherwise crash.

There must be a more proper solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the name of your project is a mistake. The `Q`-prefixed namespace is taken. You should not be having any `Q`-prefixed classes in any project that uses Qt. You should rename the project to `DataflowCanvas`, for example.

There are three solutions:

1. Hold all children by value, order the children according to their dependencies. The `QWidgetPrivate::deleteChildren` called from `QDataFlowCanvas` will be a no-op, or at least it won't be touching objects you care about.
2. Use the old `connect` syntax when connecting to the `MainWindow::onSelectionChanged` slot. Note that when your slot was invoked, the mainwindow object was of the `QWidget` dynamic type, not `MainWindow` type. The connections made using the old connect syntax **respect the dynamic type of the object**, and a connection made to a slot of given class will guarantee that the object is of that class *dynamically*, i.e. at runtime.
3. Clear the selection in the destructor - then no futher selection changes will be handled.

The first solution makes everything explicit and is the one I'd use:

```
class DataFlowCanvas : public QGraphicsView {
  ...
private:
    QDataflowModel *model_;
    QDataflowTextCompletion *completion_;
    QSet<QDataflowNode*> ownedNodes_;
    QSet<QDataflowConnection*> ownedConnections_;
    QMap<QDataflowModelNode*, QDataflowNode*> nodes_;
    QMap<QDataflowModelConnection*, QDataflowConnection*> connections_;
    bool showIOletsTooltips_;
    bool showObjectHoverFeedback_;
    bool showConnectionHoverFeedback_;
    qreal gridSize_;
    bool drawGrid_;
    QGraphicsSecene scene_;
};
```

The scene is destructed before any other fields. Problem solved. You should hold everything else by value as well. E.g. `completion_`, etc. The pointer indirections are not useful.

The second solution highlights an unfortunate Qt bug. To wit -- in the code below, the old connect syntax will never invoke `Derived2::aSlot2`, because at the time the slot is invoked, the object isn't of the `Derived2` type anymore:

```
#include <QtCore>

int ctr1, ctr2;

struct Derived1 : QObject {
  Q_SLOT void aSlot1() { ctr1++; qDebug() << __FUNCTION__; }
  Q_SIGNAL void aSignal();
  ~Derived1() { Q_EMIT aSignal(); }
  Q_OBJECT
};

struct Derived2 : Derived1 {
  Q_SLOT void aSlot2() { ctr2++; qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << qobject_cast<Derived2*>(this); }
  Q_OBJECT
};

int main() {
  {
    Derived2 d;
    QObject::connect(&d, &Derived2::aSignal, &d, &Derived2::aSlot2);
    QObject::connect(&d, SIGNAL(aSignal()), &d, SLOT(aSlot2()));
    QObject::connect(&d, SIGNAL(aSignal()), &d, SLOT(aSlot1()));
  }
  Q_ASSERT(ctr1 == 1);
  Q_ASSERT(ctr2 == 1);
}
#include "main.moc"
```

The output clearly demonstrates the problem:

```
aSlot2 QObject(0x0)   <-- aSlot2 called but `this` is of `Derived1*` type!
aSlot1
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, it is very insightful. I tried holding `QGraphicsSecene` by value in my widget class, but I hit another similar crash of the same type (basically the same pattern: the scene's destructor deletes all objects, which emits a selectionChange signal which is handled by the client, which tries to use methods of the widget being destroyed). It seems the only way it is to clear the selection at the beginning of my widget's destructor. (I haven't tried solution #2 yet)

Answer (score 1):

I was taking it so simple :) What about just checking `canvas` pointer:

```
void MainWindow::onSelectionChanged()
{
    if (!qobject_cast<QGraphicsScene*>(canvas))
        return;

    auto selNodes = canvas->selectedNodes();
    auto selConns = canvas->selectedConnections();
    ...
}
```

I used `qobject_cast` to check if pointer `canvas` still exists. You can check in other (better) way. The code works.

Comment: Testing the value of a deleted pointer is undefined behaviour.